# How do I use pnpm in my Angular project to manage packages?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, package-managers, pnpm

I am searching for a way to have one node_modules folder to use in my different projects. I found `pnpm`, installed it, and created one project with the commands:

```
ng new test-pnpm --skip-install

ng config cli.packageManager pnpm

pnpm install

ng serve
```

This project doesn't start. When I delete this project and `.pnpm-stor folder`, I cannot install packages for the next project with `pnpm`.

Can anyone tell me the steps to use it in a project, how to configure, how to install, how to add packages, and how to use it in different projects?

Answer (score 13):

Don't remove the `.pnpm-store` folder. Only remove `node_modules` if you want to.

Try to run `pnpm install --shamefully-hoist`. If it helps, you can create a `.npmrc` file in the root of your project with `shamefully-hoist=true`.

The issue is that pnpm creates a strict `node_modules` and sometimes packages require other packages that are not declared in their `package.json`. See [pnpm’s strictness helps to avoid silly bugs](https://medium.com/pnpm/pnpms-strictness-helps-to-avoid-silly-bugs-9a15fb306308)

Answer (score 7):

You can set pnpm directly if you're creating a new project by using the following command:

```
ng new test-pnpm --package-manager=pnpm
```

You have more options related to ng new, just check the below link: https://angular.io/cli/new

Answer (score 3):

angular.json:

```
{"cli": 
  {
    "packageManager": "pnpm"
  }
}
```